# Vectorizing nested loops in matlab using bsxfun and make this code run into GPU by matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, gpu, vectorization, bsxfun

HAUSDIM Returns the Haussdorf fractal dimension of an object represented by
a binary image. I need the PARALLEL GPU code to test this on GPU from matlab using  Parallel Computing Toolbox.

### Algorithm

1. Pad the image with background pixels so that its dimensions are a 
   power of 2.
2. Set the box size 'e' to the size of the image.
3. Compute N(e), which corresponds to the number of boxes of size 'e' 
   which contains at least one object pixel.
4. If e > 1 then e = e / 2 and repeat step 3.
5. Compute the points log(N(e)) x log(1/e) and use the least squares 
   method to fit a line to the points.
6. The returned Haussdorf fractal dimension D is the slope of the line.

### Code

```
function [ D ] = hausDim( I )
maxDim = max(size(I));
newDimSize = 2^ceil(log2(maxDim));
rowPad = newDimSize - size(I, 1);
colPad = newDimSize - size(I, 2);
I = padarray(I, [rowPad, colPad], 'post');

boxCounts = zeros(1, ceil(log2(maxDim)));
resolutions = zeros(1, ceil(log2(maxDim)));

iSize = size(I, 1);
boxSize = iSize;
boxesPerDim = 1;
idx = 0;
while boxSize >= 1
    boxCount = 0;

    minBox = (1: boxSize: (iSize - boxSize) + 1);
    maxBox = (boxSize: boxSize: iSize);

    for boxRow = 1:boxesPerDim
        for boxCol = 1:boxesPerDim
            objFound = false;
            for row = minBox(boxRow) : maxBox(boxRow)
                for col = minBox(boxCol) : maxBox(boxCol)
                    if I(row, col)
                        boxCount = boxCount + 1;
                        objFound = true; % Break from nested loop.
                        break;
                    end;
                end;

                if objFound
                    break; % Break from nested loop.
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;

    idx = idx + 1;
    boxCounts(idx) = boxCount;
    resolutions(idx) = 1 / boxSize;

    boxesPerDim = boxesPerDim * 2;
    boxSize = boxSize / 2;
end;

D = polyfit(log(resolutions), log(boxCounts), 1);
D = D(1);
end
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: I need the conversion. I am not getting it actually. I need the conversion to understand it. Help needed.

Comment: can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Listed in this post is a vectorized approach killing all loops except the outermost one, which owing to the different shaped boxes needed for each such iteration makes it complicated and might not be worth the effort. So, here's the implementation after padding input array with zeros -

```
Inz = I~=0;
nrows = size(I,1);
N = log2(nrows)+1;
boxCounts_out = zeros(1,N);
for iter = 1:N
    n = 2.^(iter-1);
    matches = any(any(reshape(Inz,nrows/n,n,nrows/n,n),1),3);
    boxCounts_out(iter) = sum(matches(:));
end
resolutions_out = 1./(2.^(N-1:-1:0));
```

After that, you can use the `polyfit` code using `boxCounts_out` and `resolutions_out`.

---

For making the code runnable on a GPU, I would definitely suggest converting `Inz` and `boxCounts_out` to [`gpuArrays`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html) and then use the earlier listed code. So, perform the initializations like so -

```
Inz = gpuArray(I~=0);
boxCounts_out = zeros(1,N,'gpuArray');
```

As the operations with these inputs involve a lot of sum reduction and comparatively less memory, I would really bet for a good runtime and memory efficiency there.

Comment: Sir is this the whole conversion? I mean after function [ D ] = hausDim( I ), if I write this, is this the whole ? I gave the code there. Does your code totally convert the whole thing ? or just loop portion ?

Comment: @Ananyakhan You have to use the proposed code after the line `I = padarray(I, [rowPad, colPad], 'post');`. So, the proposed code only replaces the loop portion of your original code. Therefore, you also need to add the polyfit code after using the proposed code.

Comment: Thank you sir. In the comment portion I have added another question, needed your help also.

Comment: @Ananyakhan That exact question was [`asked earlier`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875230/how-to-convert-a-nested-loop-into-parfor-loop) on Stackoverflow. So, please refer to that question. If that doesn't solve it, post another question on Stackoverflow. But, please don't post question(s) like that as answers. That question is quite different anyway. I would request you to delete that newly added post of yours.

Comment: Ok sir. I am posting it again as a question.

Comment: @Ananyakhan That won't solve it anyway, because it's the exact same question! You have to tell us why that earlier asked question didn't solve it for you, as in what's different. It will be closed as a duplicate, if the question stays the same.

Comment: ok sir. I need help like you did here. I am new totally , so what the answer was , were clear, but I need straight answer like you'v given here.

Comment: Sir how to get help from that ?

Comment: @Ananyakhan Hmm, I assuming that earlier asked was from you. So, you can message the answerer under his answer asking for a simple way to solve it, can you?

Comment: Ok sir. I can. I am expecting your response under that thread.

Comment: @Ananyakhan Also, if the question in this post has been answered by this answer, consider accepting it. Read more about accepting answers here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work